# current location with android

Tags: android, gps, currentlocation

I want to add a google map with a current location. How can I do this? I found this code but the location is static. How can I correct it?

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    int ZOOM_LEVEL=15;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mTrackView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapwhere, mSupportMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        return mTrackView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        //googleMap = mMap;
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        if(mSupportMapFragment!=null){
            googleMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();
            if(googleMap!=null){
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(12.12122,
                                17.22323), ZOOM_LEVEL);
                googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have done some search on stackoverflow before asking this question, but for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-on-a)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void displayLocation() {

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

    // **************************
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); // this is the key ingredient

    // **************************
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi
            .checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can
                    // initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    dialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.allow_location));
                    dialog.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.yes),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                                    progressDialog = Utility.getProgressDialog(context);
                                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

                                    if (progressDialog != null) {
                                        progressDialog.show();
                                    }

                                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                                                        .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                                                if (mLastLocation != null) {
                                                    setUpMap(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(), "Current Location",
                                                            true);
                                                } 
                                            }
                                        }, 4000);



                                }
                            });
                    dialog.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                            setUpMap(12.9667, 77.5667, "", false);
                            Utility.showToat(context, "Select Address from the Map");
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    dialog.show();

                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed
                    // by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling
                        // startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(GoogleMapActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no
                    // way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}
```